# Python is not installing on Windows 10

Tags: python

I tried to install Python to Windows 10, with the PATH installation included. However, when I click to enter in the Python application, it just appears the setup. I need to access the Python terminal.
[Here is the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1nEX.png)

Comment: it appears Python is already installed. What happens when you type ```python -V``` on command line?

Comment: You can open a command line interface and enter the command `python` to open the python terminal. Alternatively, IDLE (python terminal) is probably installed with python, so you can search for that program on your computer

Comment: @Ruperto It appears Python 3.9.1.

Comment: @Maga2020 then ```Python 3.9.1``` is already installed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not accidentally opening the Python installation executable. Check again that the Python path is installed properly and try running the command "py" or "python" in the Command Prompt to see if it starts. If it doesn't start and Python is installed on your computer, [manually add Python's install location to your PATH.](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/4)